# Iterable O(1) insert and random delete collection

Tags: data-structures

I am looking to implement my own collection class.  The characteristics I want are:

1. Iterable - order is not important
2. Insertion - either at end or at iterator location, it does not matter
3. Random Deletion - this is the tricky one.  I want to be able to have a reference to a piece of data which is guaranteed to be within the list, and remove it from the list in O(1) time.

I plan on the container only holding custom classes, so I was thinking a doubly linked list that required the components to implement a simple interface (or abstract class).

Here is where I am getting stuck.  I am wondering whether it would be better practice to simply have the items in the list hold a reference to their node, or to build the node right into them.  I feel like both would be fairly simple, but I am worried about coupling these nodes into a bunch of classes.

I am wondering if anyone has an idea as to how to minimize the coupling, or possibly know of another data structure that has the characteristics I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Take a look at [**tries**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

#### Apparently they can beat hashtables:

> Unlike most other algorithms, tries have the peculiar feature that the time to insert, or to delete or to find is almost identical because the code paths followed for each are almost identical. As a result, for situations where code is inserting, deleting and finding in equal measure tries **can handily beat binary search trees or even hash tables**, as well as being better for the CPU's instruction and branch caches.

It may or may not fit your usage, but if it does, it's likely one of the best options possible.

Comment: Very interesting. Why isn't there any trie-based C++ standard data structure? Are there any downsides, or don't tries have strict complexity guarantees?

Comment: Wait, this looks like you can only store strings of comparable objects in tries. How would this apply to a general collection of some arbitrary type?

Comment: @Kerrek: I don't know about the first question, but regarding the second question: The downside is that they're well-suited only for string or string-like data structures. I don't think they're well-suited for every kind of storage, unlike hashtables.

Comment: I am looking at the wikipedia article, and they do sound appealing, however I am wondering how I would construct keys, since they have to be unique for each object I am storing.  I was thinking of using an int or long as the key instead of a string, and branch out on each bit.

Comment: @Mehrdad. Yeah, got it. It's an interesting structure, but also very special-purpose. Sequences of node keys make up the final stored value.

Comment: @Godric: A bitwise trie seems possible, depending on your particular application.

Comment: I am worried about generating the key from a function because any input such as fields in the stored objects might change, changing the resulting key, and making the object un-findable in the trie if I don't update it on every state change.  perhaps I could generate the key on insertion, and just store it in the object, but again this goes back to an interface or abstract class that they would all have to implement.

Answer (score 3):

It'd be hard to beat a hash map.

Comment: are hash maps iterable?  I thought they were more like a set, which didn't allow iteration.

Comment: @Godric: Sets also allow iteration.

Comment: I guess that is much simpler then.  Thanks.

Comment: @Godric: You can definitely iterate them, but the order of the result is pretty much random.

Comment: That isn't an issue.  I am guessing I will have to use a buffer for objects being added and deleted, so I don't change the collection during iteration?

Comment: Depends on the implementation.  You can use a LinkedHashMap that maintains insertion order using a backing list.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, this sounds like the perfect fit for `std::unordered_set` (that's `std::tr1::unordered_set` or `boost::unordered_set` to you if you have an older compiler). It's implemented as a hash set, which has the characteristics you describe.

Here's the [interface documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set). Note that the hash containers actually offer *two* sets of iterators, the usual ones and *local* ones which only go through one bucket.

Many other languages have "hash sets" as well, certainly Java and C#.

Comment: I have run into hash sets before (I'm using C# for this particular project).  Like I said in the comments to duffymo's answer, I didn't realize set implementations were iterable.